# How to Save files on external SD with Delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

anybody knows how to write a file on the external sd card? i checked user permissions in the manifest file and it says user can write to external sd

but everytime i try something like

TFile.copy(src, '/storage/extSdCard/file.txt')

src is a file located in the internal device memory

i receive a permission denied error. Of course there is no error if i copy the file within the internal device memory path

Using Delphi XE8 on Android device Samsung S4

Comment: Try using `TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, 'file.txt')` different devices have different external storage paths. Hardcoding may point to wrong one.

Comment: thank dalija but i need to write on the extenal sd card not in the internal one

Comment: I may be wrong but `TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath` should return external one. [Standard RTL Path functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms)

Comment: tried it , it returns /storage/emulated/0/Android which is the internal one :(

Comment: Does `TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath` returns your SD card downloads path? If it does then you should report issue to Embarcadero. Don't know about XE8, but XE7 has `GetSharedFilesDir` function in `Androidapi.IOUtils` that is not called anywhere (and implemented incorrectly with `cpDOWNLOADS` instead `cpNONE`), but that could be starting point to get right path then.

Comment: i just need to write on /storage/extSdCard why it has to be so difficult, the user has permissions to write to external storage and there are so many apps which write directly on the memory cards around

Comment: Hi @user1566931, you can try [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fmxflyfilesutils/)

Comment: hello whosrdaddy i gave it a try and it exposes the same issues i'm digging in ... permission denied when it tries to write to the external sd card. i did some more tests and research and i found out according to this post http://technofaq.org/posts/2014/04/fixing-external-sd-card-write-issue-on-android-kitkat/ that since kitekat 3rd party apps may no longer write to external sd card .... this is madness !!! i can't believe it

Comment: @user1566931: that is not entirely true. An app *can* still write to an external SD card, but *only* to a folder that the app created/owns. The article you linked to even says as much.

Comment: yes i read it too.... the problem is you are not really allowed to create any folder on the external sd card (at least not with lollipop) i've tried both with createdirectory and forcedirectory it always says permission denied. try it