# Sqlite Database Backup and Restore in Delphi

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi

is there any way to backup and restore SQLite database in android using Delphi 10.2 Firemonky FireFac. 
I am using the following code but it is not generating any backup file and i want to save backup file in SDcard(currently try to save in current directory);

```
procedure TFMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var pathname : string;
begin
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
pathname := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
{$ENDIF}
FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite';
FDConnectionMain.Params.Values['Database'] := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'ConceptDB_Backup.s3db');
FDConnection1.Open();
    FDSQLiteBackup1.Database := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(pathname, 'ConceptDB.s3db');
    FDSQLiteBackup1.DestDatabaseObj := FDConnection1.CliObj;
    FDSQLiteBackup1.Backup;
    ShowMessage('Backup Successfully');
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `smCreate` (default) mode is a right choice for a just created backup database. I would expect exception though.. Still, why not just fill `Database`, `DestDatabase` properties and call `Backup`?

Comment: @Victoria file now created, but how can i save backup file to SDcard and how to restore procedure execute

Comment: Ehm, by changing `DestDatabase` path to that SD card? And there is no restore in SQLite. Backup API exists mainly for doing backups over opened databases and produces ready to open databases.

Comment: @Victoria i try to give Sdcard path Permission Denied and try to copy the database to SDcard same error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693009/how-to-save-files-on-external-sd-with-delphi-xe8) i think other people facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How to backup SQLite database?

You have a typo in your code. You've defined database name for a different object. I don't know the meaning of those objects, but if you're about to backup an opened database (which SQLite backup API is primarily for) into a file defined by name, then you can write code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BackupPath: string;
  BackupFile: string;
begin
  BackupPath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
  BackupFile := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(BackupPath, 'MyBackup.db');

  FDSQLiteBackup1.DatabaseObj := FDConnection1.CliObj as TSQLiteDatabase;
  FDSQLiteBackup1.DestDatabase := BackupFile;
  FDSQLiteBackup1.Backup;
end;
```

Or define source and target database by file names:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CommonPath: string;
  SourceFile: string;
  BackupFile: string;
begin
  CommonPath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
  SourceFile := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(CommonPath, 'MySource.db');
  BackupFile := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(CommonPath, 'MyBackup.db');

  FDSQLiteBackup1.Database := SourceFile;
  FDSQLiteBackup1.DestDatabase := BackupFile;
  FDSQLiteBackup1.Backup;
end;
```

The whole thing is about 2 properties and one method call. You always specify either source object or source file name, and target object or target file name.

### How to restore SQLite database?

Backup files created by the [**SQLite backup API**](https://sqlite.org/backup.html) (which is used by [**TFDSQLiteBackup**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.SQLite.TFDSQLiteBackup) component) are just database copies, so they don't need to be processed anyhow more and can be opened the same way as their original.

### How to write a file to an external storage?

Using external storage (if that's what you mean by SD card) for your datatabase backup files might be done if you keep the **Write external storage** option in your project settings enabled, and for the backup file build a path e.g. by [**using this code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34730379/8041231) (it implements the [**getExternalStorageDirectory**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) method). Your code might become (it's untested):

```
uses
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
  JEnvironment = interface;

  JEnvironmentClass = interface(JObjectClass)
  ['{D131F4D4-A6AD-43B7-B2B6-A9222BC46C74}']
    function _GetMEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_CHECKING: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_EJECTING: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_MOUNTED: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_NOFS: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_REMOVED: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_SHARED: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_UNKNOWN: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetMEDIA_UNMOUNTED: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_ALARMS: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_DCIM: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS: JString;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_MOVIES: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_MUSIC: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_PICTURES: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_PODCASTS: JString; cdecl;
    function _GetDIRECTORY_RINGTONES: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function init: JEnvironment; cdecl;
    {class} function getDataDirectory: JFile; cdecl; 
    {class} function getDownloadCacheDirectory: JFile; cdecl;
    {class} function getExternalStorageDirectory(): JFile; cdecl;
    {class} function getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(type: JString): JFile; cdecl;
    {class} function getExternalStorageState(path: JFile): JString; cdecl; 
    {class} function getExternalStorageState: JString; cdecl;
    {class} function getRootDirectory: JFile; cdecl;
    {class} function getStorageState(path: JFile): JString; cdecl; 
    {class} function isExternalStorageEmulated: Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function isExternalStorageEmulated(path: JFile): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function isExternalStorageRemovable(path: JFile): Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} function isExternalStorageRemovable: Boolean; cdecl;
    {class} property MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL: JString read _GetMEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL;
    {class} property MEDIA_CHECKING: JString read _GetMEDIA_CHECKING;
    {class} property MEDIA_EJECTING: JString read _GetMEDIA_EJECTING;
    {class} property MEDIA_MOUNTED: JString read _GetMEDIA_MOUNTED;
    {class} property MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY: JString read _GetMEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY;
    {class} property MEDIA_NOFS: JString read _GetMEDIA_NOFS;
    {class} property MEDIA_REMOVED: JString read _GetMEDIA_REMOVED;
    {class} property MEDIA_SHARED: JString read _GetMEDIA_SHARED;
    {class} property MEDIA_UNKNOWN: JString read _GetMEDIA_UNKNOWN;
    {class} property MEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE: JString read _GetMEDIA_UNMOUNTABLE;
    {class} property MEDIA_UNMOUNTED: JString read _GetMEDIA_UNMOUNTED;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_ALARMS: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_ALARMS;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_DCIM: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_DCIM;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_MOVIES: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_MOVIES;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_MUSIC: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_MUSIC;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_PICTURES: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_PICTURES;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_PODCASTS: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_PODCASTS;
    {class} property DIRECTORY_RINGTONES: JString read _GetDIRECTORY_RINGTONES;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/os/Environment')]
  JEnvironment = interface(JObject)
  ['{83A2E94E-7D8E-432F-BE21-AEC2115015BE}']
  end;

  TJEnvironment = class(TJavaGenericImport<JEnvironmentClass, JEnvironment>);

function GetExtStgPath: string;
var
  Path: JFile;
begin
  Path := TJEnvironment.JavaClass.getExternalStorageDirectory;
  Result := JStringToString(Path.getAbsolutePath);
end;

function IsExtStgWritable: Boolean;
var
  State: JString;
begin
  State := TJEnvironment.JavaClass.getExternalStorageState;
  Result := State.equals(TJEnvironment.JavaClass.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SourcePath: string;
  SourceFile: string;
  BackupPath: string;
  BackupFile: string;
begin
  if not IsExtStgWritable then
    raise Exception.Create('The external storage is not writable!');

  SourcePath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
  SourceFile := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(SourcePath, 'MySource.db');
  BackupPath := GetExtStgPath;
  BackupFile := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(BackupPath, 'MyBackup.db');

  FDSQLiteBackup1.Database := SourceFile;
  FDSQLiteBackup1.DestDatabase := BackupFile;
  FDSQLiteBackup1.Backup;
end;
```

Comment: Here {class} function getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(type: JString): JFile; cdecl; i got this [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(63): E2029 Identifier expected but 'TYPE' found and change with  {class} function getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(): JFile; cdecl;. File now saving to internal Storage instead of external

Comment: I'll try to setup environment for Android and test this. But it takes me some time. I don't think that applications have access to the whole external storage though, so I would beware of using hardcoded paths and use that [Environment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) interface. I'll try to go deeper :)

Comment: i find this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766016/how-to-get-sd-card-path-in-android6-0-programmatically/40205116#40205116) but don't know how to use in Delphi might be it gives you an idea how to use it.

Comment: It wants FDSQLiteBackup1.DriverLink , what should I set?